# Open XML вывод списка в документ Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, excel

Мне нужно вывести в документ Excel список Требований. Примерно так:

1. Описание требования №1
2. Описание требования №2
3. и т.д.
    ...
   То есть цифры 1,2,3,4 и т.д. в ячейках первого столбца, а текстовое описание в ячейках 2-го столбца документа Excel.

Вот мой метод. Он создает документ и выводит в первую ячейку первой строки строку "Номер версии такой-то".
А вот с циклом проблемы, выводит только "1." и ошибку вместо описания требования.

**Внимание сделала вот так!**

```
public void Excel()
        {
            var viewModel = new RequirementIndexData();
            viewModel.Requirements = db.Requirement;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();                
            SpreadsheetDocument dc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);                
            WorkbookPart mdp = dc.AddWorkbookPart();
            WorksheetPart wsp = mdp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            Workbook wb = new Workbook();
            FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
            fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";
            Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();

            SheetData sd = new SheetData();
            Row r1 = new Row() { RowIndex = (UInt32Value)1u };

            Cell c1 = new Cell();
        c1.DataType = CellValues.String;
        c1.CellValue = new CellValue("Номер версии " + viewModel.Requirements.OrderBy(r => r.CreatedOn).Select(r => r.CurentVersion).First().ToString());
        r1.Append(c1);
        sd.Append(r1);

        for (int i = 2; i < viewModel.Requirements.Count() + 2; i++)
        {
            Row row2;
            row2 = new Row()
            {
                RowIndex = (UInt32)i,
                //Spans = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "1:5" },
                Height = 25,
                DyDescent = 1.50D,
                Hidden = false,
                Collapsed = false
            };
            Cell cell2 = new Cell();
            cell2.DataType = CellValues.String;
            cell2.CellValue = new CellValue((i - 1).ToString() + ". " + viewModel.Requirements.OrderBy(r => r.CreatedOn).Select(r => r.Definition).ElementAt(i-2).ToString());
            row2.Append(cell2);
            sd.Append(row2);
        }
            ws.Append(sd);
            wsp.Worksheet = ws;
            wsp.Worksheet.Save();
            Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
            sheet.Name = "specification";
            sheet.SheetId = 1;
            sheet.Id = mdp.GetIdOfPart(wsp);
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            wb.Append(fv);
            wb.Append(sheets);

            dc.WorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
            dc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            dc.Close();
            string filename = "specification.xlsx";
            Response.Clear();
            byte[] dt = ms.ToArray();

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
            Response.BinaryWrite(dt);
            Response.End();
        }
```

И еще вопрос, как задать ширину ячейки, чтобы она была по ширине текста, а то текст большой и в маленькую ячейку не помещается.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указываете столбцы документа:

`var columns = new Columns();
for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.Requirements.Count(); i++)
{
    var col = new Column {Min = i+1, Max = i+1, Width = 20D, CustomWidth = true};
    columns.Append(col);
}
ws.Append(columns)`

И зачем здесь массив строк (Row[] rows)?

Comment: Спасибо, но я не очень поняла, куда или вместо чего вставлять этот код?

Comment: Практика показала, что не так уж важно, но я всегда объявляю столбцы перед объявлением первой строки.